# Control JIT debug popup

Tags: c#, asp.net, jit

Is it possible to direct the "JIT debug" window to a certain user.

We have a test server with a system consisting of IIS/ASP/ASP.NET. Like in some other systems, we sometimes encounter bugs which causes the JIT debugger popup to be displayed at the server.

Many users may be logged in to this test server using Remote desktop and it appears(?) to be the one first connecting to the server that receives the popup.

We could turn it off but it is many times a good hint on where the bugs are.
Is it possible to control in what session this popup appears? For a certain user for example?